# node.js/browserify require() not working on variable, but does work on string literal

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, require

```
    const x = 'ui/SelectBox.js';
    const module = require(x);
```

does not work (Error: Cannot find module 'ui/SelectBox.js'), but somehow

```
    const module = require('ui/SelectBox.js');
```

works. Also, if I call node on the commandline and do

```
var x = 'ui/SelectBox.js'; require(x);
```

it does work.

I'm doing it on a win10 machine, but also tested the same thing under debian and got the same result. Oh, and I'm using watchify (tried it with browserify itself, to the same results...).

```
node --version
```

-> v5.6.0

EDiT: Okay, read my own answer. It might save you some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the riddle is, as always, depressingly simple.

You cannot abstract your require()s if you use browserify, because (I guess) browserify parses your source for requires.

So if you absolutely have to require() over a variable, make an object that maps names to require()d modules, and then use that.

Comment: This works fine on node v5.12.0 - `const index = "."; var app = require(index)` also works fine for node modules.  I'm also surprised that  `require('ui/SelectBox.js')` doesn't throw.  It should be `require('./ui/SelectBox.js')` and `const x = './ui/SelectBox.js'; require(x)` also works fine for me...